# CVE-2015-4852: Infected traffic pattern

Tags: exploit, webserver, apache

Assuming that my Weblogic server is compromised by this vulnerability, what would the traffic pattern look like?

I'm assuming I would see HTTP requests attempting to make connections directly from WebLogic back to the Internet. Could someone provide insight? It is possible that I would see t3 traffic? I don't think an exploited server would attempt to communicate back out using t3.

Answer (score 1):

For this CVE, you should see T3 traffic which would contain embedded serialized objects. See the [poc](https://github.com/foxglovesec/JavaUnserializeExploits/blob/master/weblogic.py) for more.